# What are the best repertoire books for White with the English Opening?

Tags: opening, english-opening, repertoire

What are the best repertoire books, from White's point of view, with the English Opening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Grandmaster Repertoire series, there are three books covering the English opening from white's perspective, written by GM Marin in 2009 and 2010: [Volume 1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1906552045), [Volume 2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/190655238X) and [Volume 3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1906552592).

More recently, in 2016, [IM Cummings](https://www.everymanchess.com/opening-repertoire-the-english) wrote a repertoire book based on e3 systems, rather than fianchettoing the bishop with g3.

**Update:** In 2018, a new repertoire series from white's point of view is published: The Modern English, written by GM Georgiev and IM Semkov. In [Volume 1](https://www.newinchess.com/the-modern-english-1-c4-e5), the authors discuss 1.c4 e5.

Answer (score 2):

For many years the standard work on the English was the four volume series written by John L Watson - "English I: ...P-K4", "English II: ...N-KB3", "English III: ...P-QB4", "English I: ...Other Lines". Written in descriptive notation and republished a few years ago by Harding Simpole.